# Is it possible to use split function with a '.' as a delimiting regular expression?

Tags: java

I wanna split the content of a string variable, but I wanna use the point as a delimiting regular expression, my code doesn't work.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String [] a){
        String ch = "r.a.c.h.i.d";
        String[] tab;
        tab=ch.split(".");
        System.out.println(tab.length);
        for(String e : tab)System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `tab=ch.split(".");` to `tab=ch.split("\\.");`. You need to escape the dot because otherwise it's treated as a special character in the regex passed to split.

Comment: It's a shame Java doesn't let us use `@` to denote string literals like C# does

Comment: @user3189142 it is indeed a shame! Not the only thing I wish Java had that's already in C#.

Answer (score 1):

```
tab = ch.split("\\.");
```

One slash is the escape character for the regex.  But in Java you need to have a second slash because you have to escape the first slash.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.  In a regular expression, [`.` means any character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

> **Predefined character classes**
>
> .       Any character (may or may not match line terminators)

So you must escape it to provide the literal `.` meaning.  Escape it with a backslash character, providing two backslashes, because Java needs the backslash character itself escaped.

Use the regular expression `"\\."`.

In general, to get the literal characters out of an expression that may contain special-meaning characters, you can use the [`Pattern.quote` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-).

> This method produces a String that can be used to create a Pattern that would match the string s as if it were a literal pattern.

```
split(Pattern.quote("."))
```